Snowflake: where do the alerts live?
Maybe a newbie question but I am creating an Alert on Snowflake and specifying a Database / Schema to it but I can't seem to find it in the tree of objects on the console. Is the Alert some kind of special object in Snowflake that doesn’t get listed in the tree? I can see Tasks, Procedures, Tables, Functions and Views under the schemas in the tree but for some reason the alerts don't come up so I thought Id ask.


Looks like you don't see the alerts like tables, views and other objects, as mentioned you can run show alerts or if you want to see the execution history you can select from alert_history.

Got you, thanks for your help. I wonder why it does not come up as an object like tables and views?

Use the SHOW ALERTS command to show all alerts in the current account, schema, or DB of your choice.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-alerts

Sure but why do they not show up in tree?

Because the Snowsight UI still doesn't show those objects in the tree (it's an UI choice)

Got you, thanks again for your help Felipe!! I was very intrigued why it won’t show up…
